# What alternatives are there to ssh2 for node 8.10?

Tags: node.js, sftp

I need to download a TXT file from a SFTP server, I used ssh2-sftp-client and it worked perfectly but our production server runs on node 8.10 and the dependency requires 10 or higher.

Upgrading the node on the production server at this time is not an option, so I need an alternative to download the TXT file from the SFTP server that will work on node 8.10.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using the version 2.5.2 of ssh2-sftp-client.